# snowflake validate function not showing errors

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using below code .actual file has data with pipe(|) but to check errors  i used comma(,)
script is given below.

```sql
create or replace stage bulk_copy_example_stage 
  url = 's3://snowflake-essentials/ingesting_data/new_customer';

select * from customer;

copy into customer
from @bulk_copy_example_stage
pattern     = '.*.csv'
file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = ',' skip_header = 1);
```

When I run this query i got error.

I am checking  error by using validate function but i am getting null.

```sql
select * from table(
  validate(customer, job_id=>'01955b28-00e1-af61-0000-0000246d4489')
);`
```

How to check the errors occurred when use copy into table syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate only makes sense if you are using `on_error` - otherwise you just get the first error, the load stops and that's it.

Try adding for example `on_error=skip_file` to your file format, I'm sure it's going to work in this case